# Is there an easy way to count different matches with one SQLite query?

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite table, and I could do three different queries, like this pseudoSQL...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE day=today AND colA = "xxx";
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE day=today AND colB = "yyy";
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE day=today AND colC = "zzz";
```

I essentially want to know if there are any matches (and if so, which column) for today.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Not if they're in separate columns. You could `UNION ALL` the three queries, but that's not much of an improvement. What does your schema look like?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  SUM(O.A) A,
  SUM(O.B) B,
  SUM(O.C) C
FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN T.colA = 'xxx' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END A,
    CASE WHEN T.colB = 'yyy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END B,
    CASE WHEN T.colC = 'zzz' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END C
  FROM
    myTable T
  WHERE
    T.day = today
  ) O
;
```

Comment: if you add T.* in the inner select then you have all columns, this could be enough for you (might add where a + b + c > 0) without the outer select (usually used to group).